# iOS 7 MPVolumeView change size

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am using this code to change the Volume bar - `MPVolumeView` - in IOS 7 :

```
UIImage *minImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"VolumeBarBlueFull.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 4, 0, 4)];
UIImage *maxImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"VolumeBarGreyEmpty.png"];
UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"VolumeThumb.png"];

[[MPVolumeView appearance] setMinimumVolumeSliderImage:minImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[MPVolumeView appearance] setMaximumVolumeSliderImage:maxImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[MPVolumeView appearance] setVolumeThumbImage:thumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[MPVolumeView appearance] setVolumeThumbImage:thumbImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

This is the images:

[image]
[image]

And i noticed that if i want to change the `MPVolumeView` width with `setFrame` method to smaller width the volume bar stay in the same size.

but if remove the code above from my code(return to normal `MPVolumeView`) the width changes perfect.

Any idea what can be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
UIImage *maxImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"VolumeBarGreyEmpty.png"];
```

Into:

```
UIImage *maxImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"VolumeBarGreyEmpty.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 4, 0, 4)];
```

Just as you did with minImage.